# Is there a way to remove extra verbage on screen when using cscript?

Tags: cmd, wsh

I am working on a project in my spare time to make my life easier at work but when I put in a cscript for looking at what the default printer is on my script I get extra verbage that I do not want to show up.  Is there a way to remove this

[image: Extra Verbage that I would like to remove.]

Thanks for any assistance that you all can provide for me on this.  I am new to all this, and all the research I have done has not helped me in any way yet. If it can be done, great.

Comment: I guess when you word what you are looking for the correct way you will find your own answers.  I just needed to add /nologo behind the cscript.  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Type `cscript /?` for help. So `cscript //nologo`.